# Object passed in function pointer to other thread - how is it handled?

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

Imagine such code, that creates lambda function and passes it to other thread to be executed (method *schedule_task_in_thread* expect *Functor* as only parameter). What exactly happens to object *o*? Is there a temporary copy created until the *method* is executed? The *wait()* ensures the call is blocking.

```
 #define INVOKE_IN_MYTHREAD(method_name, ...) \
                return schedule_task_in_thread( [&](){ return mythread->method_name(__VA_ARGS__); }).wait().

    void do_something( MyObject o ){
       INVOKE_IN_MYTHREAD( method, o );
    }
```

The problem is, that the *mythread->method()* reports the object o to be slightly different than it was in *do_something()*. I tried to catch all {copy|default|move}{constructor|assignments} but I don't see them being called.

```
class MyObject{
  uint32_t a;
  std::string b;
  CryptoPP::Integer c;
}
```

Fields *a* and *b* are passed properly, field *c* is set to *Integer(0)*. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Will try to create one, but this is quite complex environment, so it will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda is reference capturing all the arguments to the method, and those references are only valid while the calling thread is in the body of do_something.

If you instead have the lambda capture by value, there will be a copy.

Safer than your macro would be something like

```
template <typename Method, typename ... Args>
void invoke_in_mythread(Method method, Args ... args)
{
    schedule_task_in_thread( [=](){ return mythread->method(std::forward<Args...>(args)); }).wait();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that also. However, the call is blocking (since the wait() waits for the method to be scheduled and executed), so the program won't leave the do_something() until mythread->method is finished. That is not the problem.